# best approach to render site-wide elements using Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, plugins

I'm using the 'modules' front controller resource for the project setup.
What's the best approach to render site-wide elements, like navigation?

- Add the action which renders the element to the end of the action stack each request?

  - is it OK to render these elements through controller actions?
- Create a plugin which renders the element?

  - Could I use module specific plugins?
- are there other possible ways to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the action stack should be avoided. [See this article for why](http://www.rmauger.co.uk/2009/03/why-the-zend-framework-actionstack-is-evil/).

The plugin method could work or you can create ViewHelpers which you call from you layout script. I like the ViewHelpers method because it keeps everything very clear. You know that when you echo out $this->mainNaviation() that there is a ViewHelper called MainNavigation.

Comment: Thx for thr article. The view helper does idd seem a good idea. One more question: how do you call namespaced viewhelpers? $this->module_mainNav() ?

Comment: You can't really call ViewHeleprs from different namespaces. You can set which ViewHelpers will be called by setting the helperPath. See http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.paths. You can use that to call one ViewHelper in module A, B, C but a more specific one in module D.

Comment: Then it becomes quite useless if I can't use it from within other components? If i have a MainNav inside a menu module, i can only display the navigation when inside the menu module.... or I should inspect my whole module directory to manually add all helper directories :s

Comment: I dont't think I explained that very well. You can create a hierarchy such that there is a default mainNav() ViewHelper and a module specific mainNav() ViewHelper. From your layout you can just call $this->mainNav(). In your modules, you can set it up so that the module ViewHelpers get called instead of the normal ViewHelpers. This explained in the link I posted. They call it stacking.